# Debugging SQL Server 2012 stored procedure - can't step into code line by line

Tags: sql-server, debugging, stored-procedures

Using: SQL Server 2012

In my list of stored procedures, I find one, right-click then click "Modify", then try to debug the stored procedure. I press F11 to step into the script but once I get to the ALTER PROCEDURE keyword, the rest of the script is highlighted and, I presume, "stepped into" simultaneously and I cannot go line by line. How can I execute the stored procedure with parameter values and also step through it so that I can see how the code behaves at runtime?

[image]

Comment: I did use Google first. Those results got me to a point where I had to ask my question and I did not see a similar question anywhere on Stack Overflow. This comment is not helpful.

Comment: Great. The passive-aggression in the original comment was not useful or necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: You can't go through the Object Explorer to debug the procedure; rather, you have to write a script that executes the procedure with parameter values like so:

exec procedure_name param1, param2;

Then the debugging mode works.